# Why Is Linkbucks API Returning Adblocker True With PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I'm working on an API to fetch original links from a site linkbucks. But whenever I access the link in browser, its okay. But when I fetch it with cURL, I get the following json response:

```
Real: {"Success":true,"AdBlockSpotted":true}
Expected: {"Success":true,"Url":"http://www.sitehere.com/"}
```

How and why does it consider my request as an adblocker enabled one?

Comment: How are you displaying the ads?

Comment: I'm not displaying the ads. I'm simply fetching original link for user instead of waiting for 5 seconds. For instance, say this link: `http://www.linkbucks.com/DB3z`

Comment: `"I'm not displaying the ads..." == "AdBlockSpotted":true` Seriously, surely the api documentation has something to say about this?

Comment: The API is not official. That's a project I'm working on. I don't know how the server is recognizing as a cURL request with adblock enabled and a normal HTTP request from browser as non-adblock. I'm tried it with file_get_contents but same result. I checked all the request headers, they all are same for both type of requests (cURL and normal)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a delay of 5 seconds before you make the request. That's required because Linkbucks wants you to wait and look at ads before moving on.

In PHP:

```
sleep(5);
```